# Calculating spindle current if measuring 3 phase line current

Tags: current, current-measurement, three-phase, cnc

I currently have a spindle that is being powered by a 3 phase supply. I am measuring the line current in each of the 3 cables using 3 current transducers. I am trying to calculate the instant
instantaneous spindle current from these line current measurements and wanted to know how I would do this with the 3 measurements?

Comment: I’m not sure what you’re asking. If we assume the spindle is powered by a 3 phase motor, then the current is what you measure. It should be near identical for all three phases. The electricity company charges you by this current, so what current do you want to measure?

Comment: @Kartman I am trying to calculate the live spindle current using the measurements from the 3 phase supply currents.

Comment: All three currents should be close to identical, so just average the three. Normally you’d only measure two as the third can be derived even if there is an imbalance with the load being an induction motor.